# Помогите разобраться в bool|string

Tags: php

Есть функция:

```php
public function sendMessage ($text, $chat_id, $keyboard): bool|string
{
    $request_params = array(
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text' => $text,
        'reply_markup' => $keyboard);
        
    return file_get_contents($this->api_link . '/sendMessage?' . http_build_query($request_params));
}
```

PhpStorm рекомендует добавлять `: bool|string`. Объясните пожалуйста что это и зачем оно нужно.

Comment: типизация https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.declarations.php    ... https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/php-basics/lessons/type-hinting/theory_unit

Comment: Читаем документацию по функции `file_get_contents` - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents и видим, что она может возвращать как `string` так и `false` т.е `boolean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип возвращаемого значения функции. В данном случае функция должна вернуть содержимое файла в виде строки или false если файл не может быть открыт по какой-либо причине. Подробнее про типы данных: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.declarations.php